# Topological spaces from compact Hausdorff zero dimensional spaces

Tags: general-topology

I saw a construction of general topological spaces using compact Hausdorff zero dimensional topological spaces, but I have no clue now of the construction or reference to this. I would be thankful if some one could provide me the construction, and/or references to this.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about Stone spaces. These are connected with Boolean algebras. There is a discussion of this topic in Chapter 2 of the book on mathematical logic by Cori and Lascar. The discussion there is of course related to logic and Boolean algebras. Johnstone has what looks like a more advanced book on the subject. See the bibliography here: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Stone_space

Comment: Yes, it seems to construct any topological space from Stone Spaces; some kind of a colimit-limit! I do not remember completely, but I would like a reference to such.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to suggest beyond these references.